# jQuery+ AJAX + Help Hiding This Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

First of all: I hope the following question is not too generic.

I have a small problem and I cant think of a good solution and I was hoping some1 here is able to help me.

This is my situation:

I am using AJAX to dynamically load pages. My main site is `index.php` and once I click on a navigation link, the AJAX script replaces the content of `index.php` with new content and adds a hash tag to the URL. For instance:

I click on the link to `about.php`, the script adds `#about.php` to the URL and loads content from `about.php` into `index.php`. It works great :) However, there is a small issue that I would like to resolve:

Lets say we start by navigating to `index.php#about.php` directly - this means the content of `index.php` is visible for 2,3 seconds and than gets replaced with content from `about.php`. And I would like to **avoid that**.

I came up with a few ideas, but they are all not really great:

**1)** Hide content -> than make AJAX call -> on completed AJAX show content again

**Downside:** The content is still visible for a second.

**2)** Hide content with CSS and show it after AJAX call

**Downside:** This would work perfectly, but users without Javascript (and the GoogleBot) will see an exmpty page only.

**3)** Use an empty `index.php` and put the content of it in `main.php` and automatically load `main.php` via AJAX on page load.

**Downside:** Would work too, but again, users without JS and GoogleBot will just see an empty page when the visit `index.php`

Thats all I can think of and all three solutions are not good, because I am worried the SEO value will dramatically decrease when I have an empty `index.php` (I could accept that users with no JS get nothing to see).

p.s. I read somewhere that when you have `display:none` in an external css file and block it with `robots.txt`, GoogleBot wont know the difference, but I am worried thats maybe not the case? Any1 got some experience?

**Edit:** I guess my whole question comes down to this:

Do you think hiding the whole content of `index.php` with CSS (and than show it with JS), will be a huge no-go for SEO or will it be okay with GoogleBot (afterall the content is still in the source, but not visible to the user)?

Answer (score 2):

If you used query strings instead of the hash you could have index.php load the correct content at the server level.

A plugin like [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) can help you push URLS to the browser so that you still get your ajax browsing.

Comment: Thats an interesting plugin! I am using a similar one, but it works with hashes only. I am gonna take a look at the demos and maybe change my site to use this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Wow where to start...first of all the page 'blink' I'll call it is 2-3 seconds for you but it is completely dependent on the users computer, how fast it executes the javascript, and how fast the AJAX call returns so you could have a much larger delay.

Second I wouldn't worry about Googlebot seeing any of the ajax content.  While it's true googlebot does try to fiddle with some javascript it won't make the ajax call like a normal browser would.  I'd be very surprised if Googlebot ever saw any of your Ajax loaded data.

Googlebot does a fantastic job of figuring out what content is delivered via html/css to a user when they visit your page.  It also figures out if something is displayed or not and does a good job of deciding if that content is just stuffing or is something that really matters.

You're worried about what someone without javascript will see when the entirety of navigating your site is based in javascript.  This doesn't seem to reconcile.

You've got PHP available.  My suggestion is to forgo the AJAX stuff you're trying to do and do it in PHP.  You can just as easily script the same behavior in PHP as you can in AJAX.

**SEO NOTES:**
If you're looking for solid SEO results I suggest making the static (non-javascript version) page as SEO friendly as possible.  I like to 'pick the low hanging fruit' like making sure the page has one and only on H1 and that it has the most important keywords in it. [seomoz](http://www.seomoz.org) is one of the best sites I've found for seo information.

Comment: I didnt want to go into detail, but just to clarify: the navigation still works when JS is disabled (than the links behave just like normal links and the user wont notice anything) And about the 2-3 seconds: I know its not always 2-3 seconds, but I just wasnt sure how to express myself ("blink" would have been a good way to put it). Thanks for the insights on GoogleBot - I more and more think it is smarter than I thought and it will probably "understand" that I am not trying to spam by hiding certain content).

Comment: Great!  That does clarify a bit.  Googlebot is still probably not going to recognize any of the AJAX stuff however, if your links still work normally it will find them and search them as well.  For the most part, I treat Googlebot (seo stuff) exactly the same way as I treat a user with javascript turned off.

Comment: BTW google/googlebot frown heavily on keyword stuffing web pages.  Here's a link to their definition of the term. http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66358

Comment: It seems I will be fine by hiding the content of index.php with CSS (at least SEO wise), since its only one h1 tag + a search form anyways and by no means I am stuffing it with keywords. Thanks for all your effort in researching and answering! However, before I mark your answer, I am still gonna try the plugin suggested by Sinetheta to see if it would solve all problems at once!